# What are the extra levels in Mega Drive/Genesis version of The Lost Vikings?

Tags: the-lost-vikings

It is known that Mega Drive/Genesis version of *The Lost Vikings* have a few extra levels that are not found in the other versions. What are these levels?

Comment: For people unsure about me answering my own question: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 5 levels exclusive for SEGA Genesis/Mega Drive. Also, the level passwords have changed slightly in the (SNES) Japanese version. Here is the list of all The Lost Vikings passwords:

1. Space Ship

   1. STRT
   2. GR8T (or GRET)
   3. TLPT
   4. GRND
2. Prehistoric

   1. LLM0 (or LLMO)
   2. FL0T (or FLOT)
   3. TRSS
   4. PRHS
   5. CVRN
   6. BBLS
   7. TR33 (Genesis/Mega Drive)
   8. VLCN
3. Egypt

   1. QCKS
   2. PHR0 (or PHRO)
   3. C1R0 (or CIRO)
   4. SPKS
   5. JMNN
   6. SNDS (Genesis/Mega Drive)
   7. TMPL (Genesis/Mega Drive)
   8. TTRS
4. Factory

   1. JLLY
   2. PLNG
   3. BTRY
   4. JNKR
   5. RVTS (Genesis/Mega Drive)
   6. CBLT
   7. H0PP (or HOPP)
   8. SMRT
   9. V8TR (or VATR)
5. Kiddy

   1. NFL8 (or NFLT)
   2. WKYY
   3. CMB0 (or CMBO)
   4. 8BLL (or ABLL)
   5. TRDR
   6. FNTM
   7. WRLR
   8. PDDY (Genesis/Mega Drive)
   9. TRPD
6. Space Ship

   1. TFFF
   2. FRGT
   3. 4RN4 (or ARNA)
   4. MSTR

Sources:

- http://www.vgmaps.com/Atlas/Genesis/index.htm#LostVikings
- http://www.vgmaps.com/Atlas/SuperNES/index.htm#LostVikings
- http://www.the-spoiler.com/ACTION/Interplay/lost.vikings.1.html
- http://lostvikings.lordaeron.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=43
- http://tcrf.net/The_Lost_Vikings_(SNES)